# What distance measure can I use that factors in order?

Tags: python, distance, levenshtein-distance

I have a few lists that havethe same IDs that are strings. They are as follows:

```
list1 = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5"]
list2 = ["1", "2", "3", "5", "4"]
list3 = ["1", "5", "4", "3", "2"]
list4 = ["4", "2", "5", "3", "1"]
```

What measure can I use to determine the lists that are closest to each other here in terms of order? Ideally `list1` and `list2` should be the closest here.

Does the spearman correlation make sense here?

Comment: What, exactly, do you mean by "closest to each other here in terms of order"? What makes one pair of lists closer than another pair? Should `["1", "5", "4", "3", "2"]` and `["2", "1", "3", "4", "5"]` be considered closer than `["1", "2", "3", "4", "5"]` and `["1", "2", "4", "3", "5"]`?

Comment: You've tagged this levenshtein-distance, but Levenshtein distance has nothing to do with order. Spearman's correlation coefficient isn't applicable either. You don't have two rank variables to correlate, and even if you did, Spearman's correlation coefficient is a correlation coefficient, not a distance metric.

Comment: And is `list4` *supposed* to have 2 `"2"`s and no `"1"`? What space are these samples supposed to be drawn from?

Comment: Thanks @user2357112 for the observations. Ideally list1 = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5"] and 
list2 = ["1", "2", "3", "5", "4"] as mentioned has elements  1, 2 and 3  in the same positions. So out  of  five, three of  them are in the  same position. That's the order I'm referring to, so should be deemed very close Compared to list3  and list4. Sorry  I wrongly tagged Levenshtein  distance. In your opinion, how  can I measure how similar the lists are  based  on element positions as explained earlier?

Comment: So rather than lists being close to each other in the lexicographic order of all lists in whatever the sample space is, you're looking for something that captures some notion of one list's internal order being similar to another list's internal order.

Comment: Your comment talks about having the same elements in the same positions. Is that what you care about? For example, should `["1", "2", "3", "4", "5"]` and `["5", "1", "2", "3", "4"]` be considered maximally different, since they have no elements in the same positions whatsoever? Or should they be considered fairly similar, since the relative order of most elements is the same?

Comment: @user2357112, yes, having the same elements in the same positions is all I care about. ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5"] and ["5", "1", "2", "3", "4"] are considered maximally different.

Comment: You can use [`difflib.SequenceMatcher.ratio`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/difflib.html#difflib.SequenceMatcher.ratio). Demo: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bc@9CsIwEAfwvU9xdEqkCG1aEKGPoIujOKRpisHmwzSCffrYJFhFHO5/y@@OOzO7q1ZkZ6z3g9UShOPWaT1OIKTR1gHTshOKOqHVlEXSi2EYRfcGJ35/cMX4gTp25TbLRjG5Elo452VeQF6FICHqEE1@iaL6J5rEkiAf0azjJA0kUUdRrzuaVZSLyIwVyiFJn@j7CYTigQXEK1IjqdW4gGqpG5/bkcqup8D2vw@io1a8gA3DWxs2Ioyx9y8 "Python 3.8 (pre-release) – Try It Online")

Answer (score 3):

[Edit distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edit_distance) seems to be a good candidate for such a metric.

```py
from typing import List


def calcEditDistance(lhs: List[str], rhs: List[str]) -> int:
    '''
    Dynamic programming
    dp[i][j] = minimum number of operations to convert lhs[0:i] to rhs[0:j]
    '''
    m = len(lhs)
    n = len(rhs)
    dp = [[0] * (n + 1) for _ in range(m + 1)]

    for i in range(1, m + 1):
        dp[i][0] = i

    for j in range(1, n + 1):
        dp[0][j] = j

    for i in range(1, m + 1):
        for j in range(1, n + 1):
            if lhs[i - 1] == rhs[j - 1]:
                dp[i][j] = dp[i - 1][j - 1]
            else:
                dp[i][j] = min(dp[i - 1][j - 1], dp[i - 1]
                               [j], dp[i][j - 1]) + 1

    return dp[m][n]


list1 = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5"]
list2 = ["1", "2", "3", "5", "4"]
list3 = ["1", "5", "4", "3", "2"]
list4 = ["4", "2", "5", "3", "2"]

res = calcEditDistance(list1, list2)
print(f"dis[1, 2] = {res}")

res = calcEditDistance(list1, list3)
print(f"dis[1, 3] = {res}")

res = calcEditDistance(list1, list4)
print(f"dis[1, 4] = {res}")

res = calcEditDistance(list2, list3)
print(f"dis[2, 3] = {res}")

res = calcEditDistance(list2, list4)
print(f"dis[2, 4] = {res}")

res = calcEditDistance(list3, list4)
print(f"dis[3, 4] = {res}")
```

prints

```py
dis[1, 2] = 2
dis[1, 3] = 4
dis[1, 4] = 4
dis[2, 3] = 4
dis[2, 4] = 4
dis[3, 4] = 3
```

which matches your intuition.

Note that in the Python code I use the [Levenshtein distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance) where insert, delete, and replace operations are allowed. You can, of course, use other types of edit distance.

Answer (score 0):

The comments have clarified that you're looking for something where two lists are closer together the more elements they have in the same positions. In that case, just count how many elements they have in different positions:

```
def distance(l1, l2):
    return sum(1 for i, j in zip(l1, l2) if i != j)
```